# An example Safari web application with source code that supports drag drop from one browser windows to another

Tags: javascript, safari

I am trying to figure out how to implement drag and drop of (say) a URL from the address bar to a web application that I am developing. I am able to get the data in Chrome using the dataTransfer object as shown below, but the same information is not present in Safari version 10.1.

```
(dataTransfer.getData('text/uri-list')
```

The above provides me the URL on Chrome but not on Safari.

I see that on gmail web application, I can infact drag drop a link from the Safari address bar into a new email that I am composing in a different tab on Safari. So the data is available somewhere. I tried dropbox but that did not seem to support drag drop from Safari address bar.

If someone could point me to a web application with source code (or example code) that supports drag drop from one browser window to another for Safari 10.1, that will be much appreciated.